# Lagrange remainder estimate $\ln(x+1)$, $-1<x≤1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Why we can't use Lagrange remainder estimate

$$R_{n+1}≤(\max |f^{(n+1)}(t)|) \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}, \quad t∈[0,x]$$

to show that the remainder of Taylor expansion for  $\ln(x+1)$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to the $\infty$, and instead we use the integral form?
However, Calculus Salas (10th edition, p608) has mentioned that,

> [in this case, that estimate is not delicate enough to show that $R_{n+1}$ $\rightarrow$ $0$ for $x$ under consideration]

Would you please explain that to me?